# Como atualizar uma lista de documentos em mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando atualizar uma lista de objetos parecido com isso:

```
var lista = [ { _id: 57ea29361b297553c99d702f,
    nome: 'Meu nome',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 57ea29371b297553c99d7031,
    nome: 'Meu outro nome',
    __v: 0 } ]

model.update({}, lista)
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

mas me retorna isso:

> { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }

se passar apenas um da lista funciona

```
model.update({}, result[0])...
```

> { ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 }

Comment: Não tenho a certeza mas não será necessário `{multi: true}` nos argumentos ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter

Comment: já tentei model.update({}, lista, { multi: true }), não funciona.

Comment: acho que só serve para mudanças iguais para todos os documentos

Comment: Você quer atualizar o que? O `model`? Se essa lista do seu exemplo for os novos nomes para cada documento, você precisará de um update para cada doc. Tipo: `lista.forEach(function(item){ model.update({_id: item._id}, {nome: item.nome}).then(...);  });`

Comment: @sergiopereira funciona :), mas seria bom ter algo do mongodb que já faz isso, pode colocar como resposta.